# Predictive Text on textual responses to and from data points

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a predictive text application that has to/from data entries - this would become a speech based application - when a transcript picks up key words - I want to be able to provide hints for them to complete the sentence/text.

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-cache-y667cy

[image]

After the user has typed the choice - I need the "hinted" text to remain highlighted. Currently when I've entered "to" the hint appears - but then if I continue to type the text the old hint currently remains.

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import * as yup from 'yup';
import GeneralFormik from '../GeneralFormik/GeneralFormik';

import PlaceIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Place';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

import './PredictiveText.scss';

class PredictiveText extends Component {
  
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      to: [
        {
          "key": "home",
          "details": "20 Glenbrook Dr, Hillsborough CA 92591"
        },
        {
          "key": "work",
          "details": "400 S El Camino Real San Mateo, CA 92591"
        }
      ],
      from: [
        {
          "key": "Wimpole Pharmacy",
          "details": "pharmacies"
        },
        {
          "key": "JP Pharmacy",
          "details": "pharmacies"
        },
        {
          "key": "Morrisons Pharmacy",
          "details": "pharmacies"
        }
      ]
    };

    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);

    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
  }


  getSchema(){


    let schema = {
      "initialValues": {
          "command": ""
      },
      "fields": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "command",          
          "label": "",
          //"validation": yup.string('Enter your email').required("email is required"),
          //"disabled": true
        }
      ],
      "buttons": []
    }   

    return schema;

  }

  getHint(transcript){
    console.log("GET HINT1");

    let triggerOne = "(?:\\b|')(to)(?:\\b|')";
    const found = transcript.match(triggerOne);
    //let last2 = transcript.slice(-2);
    console.log("found", found);
    //console.log("last2", last2);
    //console.log("found.length", found?.length);

    let hint = "";
    if(found){
    //if(found && (last2 !== "to") ){
      //found?.length > 0
      hint = "<span>jupiter moons</span>";
    }
  
    return transcript + " " +hint;
  }

  handler(data){
    console.log("data...", data);
    let transcript = data.command;
    console.log("xxx", this.myRef.current.innerText)
    console.log("xc", this.myRef.current);

    this.myRef.current.innerHTML = this.getHint(transcript);
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <div className="PredictiveText">

            <Grid container spacing={1}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                <div className="predictive-text">
                  <GeneralFormik 
                    schema={this.getSchema()} 
                    submitHandler={this.handler}
                  />
                  <div ref={this.myRef}></div>

                  <p>Order plasters to <span>home</span></p>
                  <ul>
                    {this.state.to?.map((item, i) => {
                        return (
                          <li key={i}>
                            <div className="icon"><PlaceIcon /></div> <div className="group">to {item.key}<br/> {item.details}</div>
                          </li>          
                        )
                    })}                  
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </Grid>                
            </Grid>


            <Grid container spacing={1}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                <div className="predictive-text">
                  <p>Order plasters to <span>home</span> from <span>Wimpole Pharmacy</span></p>

                  <div className="rounded-list">
                    <h6>From local pharmacies</h6>
                    <ul>
                      {this.state.from?.map((item, i) => {
                          return (
                            <li key={i}>
                              {item.key}<br/> {item.details}
                            </li>          
                          )
                      })}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Grid>                
            </Grid>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PredictiveText;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9kxdnpL6/7/

```js
     var to = [
        {
          "key": "home",
          "details": "20 Glenbrook Dr, Hillsborough CA 92591"
        },
        {
          "key": "work",
          "details": "400 S El Camino Real San Mateo, CA 92591"
        }
      ];
      
      var from = [
        {
          "key": "Wimpole Pharmacy",
          "details": "pharmacies"
        },
        {
          "key": "JP Pharmacy",
          "details": "pharmacies"
        },
        {
          "key": "Morrisons Pharmacy",
          "details": "pharmacies"
        }
      ]
    


    function submitLoginForm(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(event.target['command'].value);
        var transcript = event.target['command'].value;

      var s = document.getElementById("textHolder");
      s.innerHTML = getHint(transcript);
        
    }      
    
    
  
  function getHint(transcript){
    console.log("GET HINT1");

    let triggerOne = "(?:\\b|')(to)(?:\\b|')";
    const found = transcript.match(triggerOne);
    //let last2 = transcript.slice(-2);
    console.log("found", found);
    //console.log("last2", last2);
    //console.log("found.length", found?.length);

    let hint = "";
    if(found){
    //if(found && (last2 !== "to") ){
      //found?.length > 0
      hint = "<span>jupiter moons</span>";
    }
  
    return transcript + " " +hint;
  }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submitLoginForm(event)">
    <input type="text" name="command">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div id="textHolder"></div>
```